# How to convert bigint to byte array in perl similar as java

Tags: arrays, perl

I am trying to replicate some java code in perl.

The operation, I need to perform is to convert Java BigInteger to byte array

**Java Code:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         BigInteger n = new BigInteger("1677259342285725925376");
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(n.toByteArray()));
    }

}
```

Output: `[90, -20, -90, 53, 78, -38, 2, -128, 0]`

As, new in perl, tried to search and got help from https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=229290

**Perl Code:**

```
sub bigint_to_bytearray {
  my $bigint = shift;
  my @bytes;
  while(1) {
    my ($q,$r) = $bigint->brsft(8);
    push(@bytes,$r+0);
    last if $q == 0;
    $bigint = Math::BigInt->new($q);
  }
  return @bytes;
}

$n = new Math::BigInt('1677259342285725925376');
my @array  = bigint_to_bytearray($n);
print "\\tOUTPUT ARRAY  = ", join ', ', @array, "\n";
```

I am getting error

```
Use of uninitialized value $r in addition (+) at path/test.pl line 11.
Use of uninitialized value $r in addition (+) at path/test.pl line 11.
Use of uninitialized value $r in addition (+) at path/test.pl line 11.
Use of uninitialized value $r in addition (+) at path/test.pl line 11.
Use of uninitialized value $r in addition (+) at path/test.pl line 11.
Use of uninitialized value $r in addition (+) at path/test.pl line 11.
Use of uninitialized value $r in addition (+) at path/test.pl line 11.
Use of uninitialized value $r in addition (+) at path/test.pl line 11.
```

Comment: Observing the docs of `BigInt` https://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.8/Math/BigInt.html, it seems `brsft` returns a single integer shifted 8 places in your case. Your call     `($q,$r) = $bigint->brsft(8);` is expecting two.

Comment: @verisimilitude, yes you are right. Thanks

Comment: That link you shared has several interesting solutions, may be you can pick on of those - depending on how optimized you want your solution to be..

Comment: @verisimilitude I have picked the solution from the same link, however, due to not any experience in perl getting stuck.

Comment: As mentioned by Athanasius [on PerlMonks](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=11105037), `Math::BigInt` has a `to_bytes` method, which is available as of version 1.999807 (distributed with Perl 5.28), but if you're on an older version, you should be able to upgrade from CPAN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't support negative numbers.

```
sub bigint_to_bytearray {
   my $bigint = shift;
   die "Negative numbers not supported" if $bigint->is_neg;

   my @bytes = unpack('c*', $bigint->to_bytes);
   unshift @bytes, 0x00 if $bytes[0] < 0;  # Add sign bit if necessary.
   return @bytes;
}
```

The above requires a relatively new version of Math::BigInt. The following is less efficient, but it works on far older versions:

```
sub bigint_to_bytearray {
   my $bigint = shift;
   die "Negative numbers not supported" if $bigint->is_neg;

   my @bytes = unpack('c*', pack('H*', substr($bigint->as_hex, 2)));
   unshift @bytes, 0x00 if $bytes[0] < 0;  # Add sign bit if necessary.
   return @bytes;
}
```

---

```
my @bytes = unpack('c*', $bigint->to_bytes);
```

can be replaced with

```
my @bytes =
   map { $_ >= 0x80 ? 0x100 - $_ : $_ }
      map ord,
         split //,
            $bigint->to_bytes;
```

and

```
my @bytes = unpack('c*', pack('H*', substr($bigint->as_hex, 2)));
```

can be replaced with

```
my $hex = substr($bigint->as_hex, 2);
$hex = "0$hex" if length($hex) % 2;
my @bytes =
   map { $_ >= 0x80 ? 0x100 - $_ : $_ }
      map hex,
         $hex =~ /../g;
```

Comment: Thanks I need to do this on AWS RDS Postgre using `plperl` function. I think 'pack' and 'unpack' are not supported on RDS as I am getting `ERROR:  'unpack' trapped by operation mask at line 8`. Is there any alternate way?

Comment: @ikegnami Thanks, for help, however, none of these workings on RDS as many functions are not available. Now I am getting `ERROR:  Can't call method "as_hex" without a package or object reference`

Comment: That means `$bigint` isn't a Math::BigInt object.

Comment: @ikegnami yes, it is `numeric` data type of postgres for handling large numbers. Your answer is absolutely correct according to the question. However, now I am trying to use this function in `plperl`.

Comment: The question asked to convert a Math::BigInt